# Am i using the word fundamental correctly?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, history

Some fundamental points both men discuss are immoral act of slavery and government corruption?

Comment: Yes, *fundamental* is used correctly, but there are other problems with your sentence. The verb *are* is not really suitable here. Beginning with *some* suggests there are rather more than two. And *are* would be fine if you were going to provide an exhaustive list of what they all were. But as you are mentioning only two of them you need to substitute *include* for *are*. You also need the indef. article before *immoral*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is past tense or present.
It looks like it should read: Some fundamental points both men *discussed* *were* immoral *acts* and government corruption.  To answer the question, yes, "fundamental" is the adjective for the noun "points", and it is used properly.

fun·da·men·tal.

[ˌfəndəˈmen(t)əl]

ADJECTIVE

1.forming a necessary base or core; of central importance